# How should option prices differ when using the Heston versus the Black-Scholes model?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, heston

I am running Monte Carlo simulations for a European Call using [Heston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model) Model and I am trying to compare them with prices calculated using Black-Scholes formula. I am not quite sure if the prices I get from the Heston model are correct.

- Is there any regularity here?
- **What should be the relation between the prices?** (should a price of a European call from Heston be greater or smaller than from Black-Scholes?)

Can anyone explain what the relation should be?

Comment: What are the parameters you're using for the Black-Scholes and Heston models, respectively. Actually your question would benefit from including in both model's definition in order to be able to "visualize" the difference more clearly.

Comment: for example Heston(
V0=0.2,rho=-0.4,kappa=3.5,theta=0.04,xi= 0.35)   BS(sigma = sqrt(theta Heston)),  same Risk Free Rate for both

Comment: It is incorrect to use BS(sigma=sqrt(theta Heston))$. In fact, they are not comparable. Generally, you need to calibrate the Heston parameters from the market, that is, from the Black-Scholes prices. Then they should be the same. On the other hand, if you have the Heston parameters, and the price from teh Heston model, then you can calibrate the volatility parameter for BS. In both cases, they are the same.

Comment: Could you please explain how the volatility for BS should be derived given I have the Heston parameters and Heston price?

Comment: For Heston, you have a stochastic variance process, while for BS, you have only a constant volatility. You can not replace the BS volatility based on a single Heston parameter. In fact, you can calibrate a volatility surface from the Heston parameters, you will notice that there are skew or smiles for the calibrated volatilities. For the calibration, you can use Newton or the bi-section method.

Comment: I have general understanding of the two models, but I have never done any  calibration like that yet, would you please outline the main idea of this method or point a good source explaining this procedure?

Comment: I cannot explain those in a few lines. But there are a lot of papers or books describing them. You may google to find out.

Comment: I understand, alternatively would you be able to give me an exemplary set of parameters which works  so that I could analyse the concept on the results?

Comment: what should be the relation between the prices from the two models?  Is there any rule of thumb or all depends on the parameters (price from either model can be higher)?

Comment: An exemplary set of parameters and the resulting option values can be found in several places, for example the book The Heston Model by Rouah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sigma_{H}\ne 0$ and $v_0\ne \theta\ne \sigma^2_{BC}$ then prices  are different in BC and Heston model.

**Especial case**

In the Black-Scholes model the dynamics of $S_t$ under risk neutral measure follow the stochastic process 
$$dS_t=(r-q)S_tdt+\sigma_{\color{red}{BC}}S_tdW^{\mathbb{Q}}(t)\tag 1$$
on the other hand
$$dS_t=(r-q)S_t+\sqrt{v_t}S_tdW^{\mathbb{Q}}_1(t)\\
\quad  dv_t=\kappa(\theta-v_t)dt+\sigma_{\color{red}{H}}\sqrt{v_t}dW^{\mathbb{Q}}_2(t)\tag 2$$
where $d[W^{\mathbb{Q}}_1(t)\,,\,W^{\mathbb{Q}}_2(t)]=\rho dt$. In CRR model we have
$$\text{Var}[v_t\big{|}v_0]=\frac{v_0\sigma_{\color{red}{H}}^2e^{-\kappa t}}{\kappa}\left(1-e^{-\kappa t}\right)+\frac{\theta\sigma_{\color{red}{H}}^2}{2\kappa}\left(1-e^{-\kappa t}\right)^2\tag 3$$

Now if we set  $\sigma_\color{red}{H}=0$ ,then
$$\text{Var}[v_t|v_0] = 0\tag 4$$
This will produce volatility that is time-varying, but $\color{red}{\text{deterministic}}$. Indeed
$$dv_t=\kappa(\theta-v_t)dt\tag 5$$
or
$$v'_t+\kappa v_t=\kappa\theta\tag 6$$
Equation $(6)$ is a linear ordinary differential equation. We can show easily
$$v_t=\theta+c\,e^{-\kappa t}\quad ,\quad c\in\mathbb{R}\tag 7$$
Set $v_0=\theta=\sigma_{\color{red}{BC}}^2$. Therefore $c=0$ and $v=\sigma_{\color{red}{BC}}^2\,.$

---

**$\color{red}{\text{Warning}\,!}$**

In the [Heston Model](http://www.danipina.com/dani/Books/claude/Heston-original-stoc.vol.pdf) we have
\begin{align}
C(t\,,{{S}_{t}},{{v}_{t}},K,T)={{S}_{t}}{{P}_{1}}-K\,{{e}^{-r\tau }}{{P}_{2}}\tag 8
\end{align}
where,for $j=1,2$

\begin{align}
& \mathbb{P}_j({{x}_{t}}\,,\,{{v}_{t}}\,;\,\,{{x}_{T}},\ln K)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\operatorname{Re}\left( \frac{{{e}^{-i\phi \ln K}}{{f}_{j}}(\phi ;t,x,v)}{i\phi } \right)}\,d\phi \tag 9 \\ 
 & {{f}_{j}}(\phi \,;{{v}_{t}},{{x}_{t}})=\exp [{{C}_{j}}(\tau ,\phi )+{{D}_{j}}(\tau ,\phi ){{v}_{t}}+i\phi {{x}_{t}}]\tag {10} \\ 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
  & {{C}_{j}}(\tau ,\phi )=(r-q)i\phi \,\tau +\frac{a}{{{\sigma_{\color{red}{H}} }^{2}}}{{\left( ({{b}_{j}}-\rho \sigma_{\color{red}{H}} i\phi +{{d}_{j}})\,\tau -2\ln \left(\frac{1-{{g}_{j}}{{e}^{{{d}_{j}}\tau }}}{1-{{g}_{j}}}\right) \right)}} \tag{11}\\ 
 & {{D}_{j}}(\tau ,\phi )=\frac{{{b}_{j}}-\rho \sigma_{\color{red}{H}} i\phi +{{d}_{j}}}{{{\sigma_{\color{red}{H}} }^{2}}}\left( \frac{1-{{e}^{{{d}_{j}}\tau }}}{1-{{g}_{j}}{{e}^{{{d}_{j}}\tau }}} \right) \tag{12}\\ 
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
  & {{g}_{j}}=\frac{{{b}_{j}}-\rho \sigma_{\color{red}{H}} i\phi +{{d}_{j}}}{{{b}_{j}}-\rho \sigma_{\color{red}{H}} i\phi +{{d}_{j}}} \\ 
 & {{d}_{j}}=\sqrt{{{({{b}_{j}}-\rho \sigma_{\color{red}{H}} i\phi )}^{2}}-{{\sigma_{\color{red}{H}} }^{2}}(2i{{u}_{j}}\phi -{{\phi }^{2}})} \\ 
 & {{u}_{1}}=\frac{1}{2}\,,\,{{u}_{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\,,\,a=\kappa \theta \,,\,{{b}_{1}}=\kappa +\lambda -\rho \sigma_{\color{red}{H}} \,,\,{{b}_{2}}=\kappa +\lambda \,,\ {{i}^{2}}=-1 \\ 
\end{align}

> We can not simply substitute $\sigma_{\color{red}{H}} = 0$ into the pricing functions,
>   because that will lead to division by zero in  the expressions for $C_j(\tau,\phi)$ and  $D_j(\tau,\phi)$.

With $\sigma_{\color{red}{H}}=0$, the
[Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)  reduces to the ordinary first-order differential equation in the Heston's article (1993) 
$$\frac{\partial {{D}_{j}}}{\partial \tau }={{p}_{j}}-{{b}_{j}}{{D}_{j}}\tag {13}$$

where $p_j=u_j i\phi-\frac 12 \phi^2$.The solution of this ODE is 
$$D_j(\tau ,\phi )=\frac{(i{{u}_{j}}\phi -\frac{1}{2}{{\phi }^{2}})(1-{{e}^{-{{b}_{j}}\tau }})}{{{b}_{j}}}\tag {14}$$
on other hand , Heston showed 
$$\frac{\partial {{C}_{j}}}{\partial \tau }=ri\phi +a{{D}_{j}}\tag{15}$$
substitute $(14)$ in $(15)$ and integrate to obtain
$${{C}_{j}}(\tau ,\phi )\ =ri\phi \tau +\frac{a(i{{u}_{j}}\phi -\frac{1}{2}{{\phi }^{2}})}{{{b}_{j}}}\left( \tau -\frac{1-{{e}^{-{{b}_{j}}\tau }}}{{{b}_{j}}} \right)\tag{16}$$
In the case $j=2$ and $\lambda=0$, we have
$$\begin{align}
  & {{D}_{2}}(\tau ,\phi )=-\frac{(i\phi +{{\phi }^{2}})(1-{{e}^{-\kappa \tau }})}{2\kappa } \\ 
 & {{C}_{2}}(\tau ,\phi )\ =ri\phi \tau -\frac{\theta (i\phi +{{\phi }^{2}})}{2}\left( \tau -\frac{1-{{e}^{-\kappa \tau }}}{\kappa } \right) \\ 
\end{align}
\tag {17}$$
We know
$${{f}_{2}}(\phi ;{{\ln S}_{t}},{{v}_{t}})=\exp\left[i\phi\,{\ln S_t}+{{C}_{2}}(\tau \,,\,\phi )+{{D}_{2}}(\tau \,,\,\phi ){{v}_{t}}\right]$$

let  $v_0=\theta=\sigma_{\color{red}{BC}}^2$, thus
$$\color{red}{{{f}_{2}}=\exp\left( i\phi \left[\ln {{S}_{t}}+(r-\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }_{BC}}^{2})\tau \right]-\frac{1}{2}{{\phi }^{2}}{{\sigma }_{BC}}^{2}\tau  \right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(i\,\phi\,\ln S_t\right)\right]\tag {18}}$$

Comment: Why $\sigma_{BC}$ rather than $\sigma_{BS}$?

Comment: I don't Understand your question.

Comment: you have $\sigma_H$ for Heston vol, i would have expected $sigma_{BS}$ for Scholes vol, but you use *BC* everywhere.

Comment: If $\lambda=\sigma_H=0$ and $v_0=\theta=\sigma^2_{BC}$ then we can say the BC model is a especial case of Heston model .

Comment: Sure, but i think it's a little misleading - why *BC*? what does it stand for?

Comment: Please note Michal's question:  "What should be the relation between the prices?"

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the parameter settings, but you should always check the risk neutral densities. One of the several complaints against BS is the underlying GBM has lower tails so it underprices OTM (out-of-the-money) options as the market is more heavy tailed.

Heston log-return density is leptokurtic (higher tails and kurtosis). See http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/xplore/tutorials/stfhtmlnode46.html

It depends on the setting of your parameters but usually Heston should give higher prices for OTM options for compatible parameter optimizations (i.e. both models' parameters are estimated using the same data).